# Best way to parse a JSONP response

Tags: objective-c, regex, json, ios5

I am calling an API, which should return a JSON file. Here is the API link: http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/hello.json

The problem is: this JSON file has something wrapping the JSON response

```
imdb$hello(JSON)
```

So the best approch that I can see is to use a regex expression to extract only what I need. Something like: `~/\((.*)\)/`.

However I would like to use the new JSON iOS5 API, which (as far as i know) only accepts NSData as input. So, I don't want to convert my response from NSData to NSString, parse that using regex, and put that in another NSData object.

Can anyone see a better/cleaner solution for that JSON parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have isn't JSON, but [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). If you're not in JavaScript, I believe the correct way to handle is just as you say, preprocess and then parse.

Comment: umm.. really well point it out. So best way it will be using a regex to parse that out?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm not good at ObjC, so there might be a method buried somewhere that I don't know about. JSONP is designed for JavaScript, because you can just execute it. Most other languages won't have that capability, so the wrapping function call needs to be stripped out, if the library doesn't offer the way to strip it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
         NSError *jsonError = nil;
         NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSRange range = [jsonString rangeOfString:@"("];
         range.location++;
         range.length = [jsonString length] - range.location - 1;
         jsonString = [jsonString substringWithRange:range ];
         NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse =
         [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                         options:0
                                           error:&jsonError];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do something like this before parsing the JSON?

```
response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"imdb$hello" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score -1):

How regular is this string. It will **always** be there?

```
// Remove @"imdb$hello(" and @")" that wraps the response string.
NSRange JSONRange = NSMakeRange(11, [responseString length] - 12);
NSString *JSONString = [responseString substringWithRange:JSONRange];

// Now you can parse as normal…
```

You will need to craft the method of peeling away the wrapper with your own level of certainty.

Comment: Its NSMakeRange.  
NSRange JSONRange = NSMakeRange(11, [responseString length] - 12);  
NSString *responseInJSON = [responseString substringWithRange:JSONRange];

Comment: @LaksGandikota thanks for the correction! Sorry for the think-o.